# Adding a Cocoa Touch Static Library as a subproject

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

How do I add a cocoa touch static library as a subproject to an application project in Xcode 4 (4.5 in this case)?

I have seen lots of screenshots that show a full project nested inside another project. However, whenever I follow the tutorials I just get a single .xcodeproj file inside my project, not a whole project (with it's own project and target etc).

[image: single file, not a subproject]

I've tried to create a workspace too - but still no luck. What am I doing wrong? I've seen many questions on SO that seem to be similar but nothing that has helped me resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried dragging in from Finder and it seemed to work for apps but not libs. @Eiko got it in the comments to another answer... It was because the project was open elsewhere at the time. If I goto File > Close Project (on the original library project in xcode) and then drag in from Finder it works.

Answer (score 0):

Drag it from finder into the sidebar of xcode.
When doing it this way just now it worked for me.

and as @Eiko points out close the project if it is open elsewhere first, since it can only be opened once...
[image: Drag it from finder]

Comment: Yes, that's a good easy way. And don't forget: You can have one project only open *once*, so you might need to close everything and then open your "main project/workspace" again.

Comment: That works for a sub-application, but not a project of type static library :(